# Alarmmanager not firing broadcastreceiver when the device is off for 1 hour or more

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am making an alarm clock app which rings an alarm at specific time. I am using AlarmManger with BroadcastReceiver. But it does not work sometimes when device is in sleep mode. But works perfectly when device is on and being used. Although im getting wakelock before firing alarm and using RTC_WAKEUP with AlarmManager but nothing helps. Please check my code below:

Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Receiver Registered in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver android:name="com.packagename.receiver.AzanAlarm"/>
```

Function which im using to set alarm

```
fun setAzan(context: Context, reqCode: Int, offset: Long, pendingIntent: PendingIntent) {
    if (offset > 0) {
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + offset, pendingIntent)
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + offset, pendingIntent)
        }
        else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + offset, pendingIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my broadcast receiver code

```
class AzanAlarm: BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
         val powerManager = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
         val wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyAppName:Azan")
         wakeLock!!.acquire(30000) // timout after 30 seconds to play comp. azan
         showAzanNotification()
    }
}
```

The alarm works and notification comes when device is awake. But does not work sometimes when device is off for a long time.

Comment: you can implement features of AlarmManager using JobScheduler class which is improved after oreo version and very useful you can find the related document here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts

Comment: Sorry JobSchedular has problems while in doze. check this https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#restrictions

Comment: AlarmManager also impacted by doze. so far, you need to get a solution for doze mode. you can refer that here https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#java

Comment: The things mentioned in it are already implemented. WakefulBroadcastReceiver handles the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK itself. but here im already getting this wake lock in receiver. I just need to ring a sound with a notification so service is also not required. Im doing it directly in receiver after getting wake lock of 30 seconds

Comment: Have you tried this on different devices? Some manufatcturers are more restrictive about waking the device up.

Comment: @David Wasser Yes. It is working almost fine on my mobile but not on my client mobile. We both have same andorid version 9  (Pie). But he is having some huawei model and im having samsung j4+. But he says other alarms apps are working fine on his device but not my app.

Comment: Some manufacturers (Huawei included) have extra power-saving features that prevent apps from being launched by `AlarmManager` if they are not already running. You need to ensure that your app is added to the list of apps that are allowed to run in the background and allowed to launch when not already running. This list is in the Android settings under "security" or "power management". Preinstalled and well-known apps (like Whatsapp) are already in the list, but other apps need to be manually added to the list.